# is this movie "I Am Kalam (2010)" shot with sony nx level camera?

Tags: camera, video-recording

Please check this video and help me to know that can we shoot same quality level movie using Sony HXR NX1 Video Camera

[image]

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The depth of field and dynamic range visible in the movie lead me to think that it was shot on film, or perhaps with a much higher-level camera. You will not be able to reproduce the look of I Am Kalam with any NX-level camera. The sensor is simply too small.

However, you could shoot a very nice movie with that camera if you paid extra-close attention to lighting. Careful control of highlights, shadows, and the shape of your light will give you a much better result than any camera you might use.

Comment: i guess most of short film maker and low budget film maker use higher range of camera and good lighting